# Best way to code PHP/MYSQL search with options

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search, filtering

So I am building a search form which has a lot of options for users to select from. As you can see from the image below a user selects a search criteria and it allows them to enter or check what they like. If this is unticked it removes all values/unchecks all the boxes.

I originally only had weight/height/gender as the search but since then have added more.

I already coded the weight/height/gender search options and it ended being a lot of if statements checking what was selected/null then creating the appropriate MYSQL queries.

I am not entirely sure how I should go about (if I should start again) with the rest of the options. Is there an easier away around this? I just need some direction so I can make this a bit more effective.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

```js
require 'functions.php';
 
 //Search data
 //$weight_min = $_POST['weight_min'];
 //$weight_max = $_POST['weight_max'];
 //$height_min = $_POST['height_min']; 
 //$height_max = $_POST['height_max'];
 //$gender_select = $_POST['gender_select'];
 
 if("" == trim($_POST['weight_min'])){
     $weight_min = '';
 }
 else
 {
  $weight_min = $_POST['weight_min'];
 }
 
 if("" == trim($_POST['weight_max'])){
     $weight_max = '';
 }
 else
 {
  $weight_max = $_POST['weight_max'];
 }
 
 if("" == trim($_POST['height_min'])){
     $height_min = '';
 }
 else
 {
  $height_min = $_POST['height_min'];
 }
 
 if("" == trim($_POST['height_max'])){
     $height_max = '';
 }
 else
 {
  $height_max = $_POST['height_max'];
 }
 
 if (!isset($_POST['gender_select'])){
     
  $gender_select = '';
 }
 else
 {
  $gender_select = $_POST['gender_select'];
 }
 
 //Show test 
 //echo "sent: weight-min: " .$weight_min. " weight-max: " .$weight_max. " height-min: ".$height_min." height-max: ".$height_max." gender-select: ".$gender_select."<p>";
 
 check_null_values($weight_min, $weight_max, $height_min, $height_max, $gender_select);
```

```js
 function check_null_values($weight_min, $weight_max, $height_min, $height_max, $gender_select)
 {
  //Weight
  if($weight_min !=null && $weight_max != null && $height_min == null && $height_max == null && $gender_select == null)
  {
   select_weight($weight_min, $weight_max);
   //echo "select_weight";
  }
  //Height
  else if($weight_min == null && $weight_max == null && $height_min != null && $height_max != null && $gender_select == null)
  {
   select_height($height_min, $height_max);
   //echo "select_height";
  } 
  //Gender
  else if($weight_min == null && $weight_max == null && $height_min == null && $height_max == null && $gender_select != null)
  {
   select_gender($gender_select);
   //echo "select_gender";
  }
  //Weight + Height
  else if($weight_min != null && $weight_max != null && $height_min != null && $height_max != null && $gender_select == null)
  {
   select_weight_height($weight_min, $weight_max, $height_min, $height_max);
   //echo "select_weight_height";
  }
  //Weight + Gender
  else if($weight_min != null && $weight_max != null && $height_min == null && $height_max == null && $gender_select != null)
  {
   select_weight_gender($weight_min, $weight_max, $gender_select);
   //echo "select_weight_gender";
  }
  //Height + Gender
  else if($weight_min == null && $weight_max == null && $height_min != null && $height_max != null && $gender_select != null)
  {
   select_height_gender($height_min, $height_max, $gender_select);
   //echo "select_height_gender";
  }
  //All
  else if($weight_min != null && $weight_max != null && $height_min != null && $height_max != null && $gender_select != null)
  {
   select_all($weight_min, $weight_max, $height_min, $height_max, $gender_select);
   //echo "select_all";
  }
  else if($weight_min == null && $weight_max == null && $height_min == null && $height_max == null && $gender_select == null)
  {
   select_none();
   //echo "select_none";
  }
  else
  {
   //echo "Please enter missing parameter";
  }
 
 
 }
```

```js
//Weight only selected
 function select_weight($weight_min, $weight_max)
 {
  include 'db_connect.php';
  $result = mysqli_query($db, 
  "SELECT * FROM character_information 
  WHERE 
  (char_min_weight BETWEEN '".$weight_min."' AND '" .$weight_max."'
  OR char_max_weight BETWEEN '".$weight_min."' AND '" .$weight_max."')
  OR
  ('".$weight_min."' BETWEEN char_min_weight AND char_max_weight
  OR '" .$weight_max."' BETWEEN char_min_weight AND char_max_weight)
  ");
  
  return get_result($result);
 }
 
 //Height only selected
 function select_height($height_min, $height_max)
 {
  include 'db_connect.php';
  $result = mysqli_query($db, 
  "SELECT * FROM character_information 
  WHERE 
  (char_min_height BETWEEN '".$height_min."' AND '" .$height_max."'
  OR char_max_height BETWEEN '".$height_min."' AND '" .$height_max."')
  OR
  ('".$height_min."' BETWEEN char_min_height AND char_max_height
  OR '" .$height_max."' BETWEEN char_min_height AND char_max_height)
  ");
  
  get_result($result);
 }
 
 //Gender only selected
 function select_gender($gender_select)
 {
  include 'db_connect.php';
  
  $result = mysqli_query($db, 
  "SELECT * FROM character_information 
  WHERE char_gender = '".$gender_select."'
  "); 
  
  get_result($result); 
  
 }
 
 //Weight + Height selected
 function select_weight_height($weight_min, $weight_max, $height_min, $height_max)
 {
  include 'db_connect.php';
  
  $result = mysqli_query($db, 
  "SELECT * FROM character_information 
  WHERE 
  ((char_min_weight BETWEEN '".$weight_min."' AND '" .$weight_max."'
  OR char_max_weight BETWEEN '".$weight_min."' AND '" .$weight_max."')
  OR
  ('".$weight_min."' BETWEEN char_min_weight AND char_max_weight
  OR '" .$weight_max."' BETWEEN char_min_weight AND char_max_weight))
  AND
  ((char_min_height BETWEEN '".$height_min."' AND '" .$height_max."'
  OR char_max_height BETWEEN '".$height_min."' AND '" .$height_max."')
  OR
  ('".$height_min."' BETWEEN char_min_height AND char_max_height
  OR '" .$height_max."' BETWEEN char_min_height AND char_max_height))
  "); 
  
  get_result($result);
 }
```

Comment: Can you post a short example of code to illustrate your current approach?

Comment: You could loop through the POST or GET values and dynamically build your query. Be sure to separate out the user values from the query.

Comment: Posted some of my code! Yeah I was thinking of doing loops. The way i have currently done it isn't great at all

Comment: You might want to define a "Filter"-Class, with the options beeing objects. That way you can simply sanitize imput, and have object arrays as function parameter.

Comment: I don't see why you'd loop anywhere for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this way :

```
if(empty($_GET['weightMin'])) {
    $weightMin= null;
} else $weightMin= $_GET['weightMin'];

if(empty($_GET['weightMax'])) {
    $weightMax= null;
} else $weightMin= $_GET['weightMax'];
```

And the statement would be :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE ((weight >= :weighttMin AND weight <= :weightMax) OR (weight >= :weightMin AND :weightMax is null) OR (weight <= :weightMax AND :weightMin is null) OR (:weightMax is null AND :weightMin is null))
```

This is pretty long when it is x < filter < y

Else if this is only one type like 'Gender' :

```
if(empty($_GET['gender'])) {
    $gender = null;
} else $gender = $_GET['gender'];
```

The SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE (gender = :gender or :gender is null)
```

If gender is selected, it will search the good one, else it returns true and doesn't impact your statement.

The combined query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE
((weight >= :weighttMin AND weight <= :weightMax) OR (weight >= :weightMin AND :weightMax is null) OR (weight <= :weightMax AND :weightMin is null) OR (:weightMax is null AND :weightMin is null))
AND
(gender = :gender or :gender is null)
```

Comment: To get MySQL to evaluate this properly and allow it to utilize indexes on the criteria instead of scanning, you need to extend this a bit by adding `IS NOT NULL` like: `((:weightMin IS NULL AND :weightMax IS NULL) OR (:weightMin IS NOT NULL AND :weightMax IS NULL AND weight >= :weightMin) OR ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's pseudo code for a common method to build the query dynamically:

```
$qry = 'SELECT * FROM character_information WHERE ';
// If the user entered a max height criteria
if ($max_height) {
   $qry .= 'char_weight <= :max_height';
} else {
   $qry .= '1 = 1';
}
$qry .= ' AND ';
// If the user entered a min height criteria
if ($min_height) {
   $qry .= 'char_weight >= :min_height';
} else {
   $qry .= '1 = 1';
}
$qry .= ' AND ';
// If the user entered a body build criteria
if ($body_build) {
   $qry .= 'char_body_build = :body_build';
} else {
   $qry .= '1 = 1';
}
$qry .= ' AND ';
...
// Prepare and bind params here
```