# Multiple MySQL Statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some issues with a MySQL query any help would be appreciated. I basically have a table that contains job information and my query is determined from multiple selects in a form. So there is `user_id`, `date_from`, `date_to` and `client_name`.

I have got the query working when user selects all fields `user_id`, `date_from`, `date_to` and `client_name` the result as displayed but I can't seem to get it working when only a `date_from` and `date_to` are selected or `client_name` and date etc.

The query need to work if just one field is selected or all field are selected.

Hop that make sense! Here is my code that has the results working when all fields all filled in.

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` 
WHERE (`job_date` BETWEEN '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from_date)) . "' AND '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to_date)) . "'    
AND `client_name`='" . $client_name . "'
AND `staff_id`= '" . $staff_id . "')
```

Comment: Then use OR instead of AND

Comment: Or, leave out the fields which the user didn't select. Except in the case of dates. You have to have two dates when you do a `BETWEEN`. So if a date isn't chosen set it to the highest or lowest possible value.

Comment: I've tried changing and to or but it doesn't work. If I select say client_name yes it work but if I select user_id and client_name it doesn't work properly it displays all the results assigned to the staff_id.

Comment: @craigb88: You have tried what?

Comment: Sorry just edited the post. Ive changed AND to OR

Answer (score 1):

Build the conditions dynamically, depending on which fields are set:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `jobs`";
$conditions = array();
if ( !empty($from_date) && !empty($to_date) ) {
    $conditions[] = "`job_date` BETWEEN '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from_date)) . "' AND '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to_date)) . "'";
}
else {
    if ( !empty($from_date) )
        $conditions[] = "`job_date` > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from_date)) . "'";
    if ( !empty($to_date) )
        $conditions[] = "`job_date` < '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to_date)) . "'";
}
if ( !empty($client_name ) )
    $conditions[] = "`client_name`='" . $client_name . "'";
if ( !empty($staff_id ) )
    $conditions[] = "`staff_id`='" . $staff_id . "'";

if ( sizeof( $conditions ) > 0 ) {
    $query .= " WHERE " . implode( " AND ", $conditions );
}
```

This will result in a query only containing fields that actually have been set. empty fields will not be in the condition.

For example. if `$from_date`, `$to_date` and `$staff_id` is set, it would result into this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `job_date` BETWEEN '2016-02-23' AND '2016-06-15' AND `staff_id`='foo'
```

Comment: Thanks i'll give this a go now. Just need to try and get it working with codeigniter too. Hopefully this will work though :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OR` condition instead of `AND`. Try as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` 
WHERE (`job_date` BETWEEN '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from_date)) . "' AND '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to_date)) . "'    
OR `client_name`='" . $client_name . "'
OR `staff_id`= '" . $staff_id . "')
```

Comment: That gives me this error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR '1970-01-01' OR `client_name`='' OR `staff_id`= '3'' at line 2

SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE `job_date` BETWEEN '1970-01-01' OR '1970-01-01' OR `client_name`='' OR `staff_id`= '3'

Comment: @craigb88 i made a mistake there, corrected the same.. plz check now

Comment: Still returns all result assigned to a staff_id when staff_id and client_name is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Doing your statement with this trick should work :

```
SELECT *
FROM jobs
WHERE (Client_name = :clientName OR :clientName is null) 
AND ...
```

If your user didn't fill client_name, the condition will be true because input will be null, and if he filled it, it will search what he wrote !

It allows you to make only one statement.

Another example here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30030510/4734085